# Node Prerender Working on First Page Load - 500 Error on Subsequent Loads

Tags: node.js, express, docker, prerender

You can verify that this is the case. Click the link, let it load, then refresh: http://www.justinmcmahon.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

Probably of significance: my app is running in a docker container on port 3000, as is the prerender server (on port 9000), both of which are running behind the official Nginx docker image.

Also maybe of significance: The top level domain has a .htaccess redirect to the www subdomain, which points to an AWS elastic IP. I'm not very smart at this yet, so that's the best way I've come up with so far to point things in the right direction.

### .htaccess redirect

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.justinmcmahon.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### Nginx docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:

 build: .
 container_name: Nginx
 hostname: nginx
 restart: always

 environment:
   - DEFAULT_HOST=www.justinmcmahon.com

 volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

 ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
   - 5984:5984
```

### Prerender Dockerfile

```
FROM node:5.2.0
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY dist /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["node", "server"]
```

I have the following at the top of my Express config:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', config.PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL));
```

Docker logs for the prerender container show a 304 status, but Express is throwing a 500

Comment: Is there an error or any output from express? A 304 from prerender shouldn't cause a 500 from express.

Comment: All the output from express looks normal. At first I had the prerender set further down in my express config and then prerender was throwing a "can't set headers after they are set" error, but that went away when I moved it to the top of the express config.

Comment: Ah great! So it's working fine now?

Comment: No, sorry if I was unclear. Moving that line to the top of the express config solved the 500 from the prerender server, but left me with the issue described in my question.

Comment: Can you check and make sure the correct URL is being sent to your Prerender server? Is there any other information that you can provide on the error you are getting? Does express show any info?

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve this issue. I've managed to reproduce it in dev, though and this is the error that occurs on the Express server: `unexpected end of file\n    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:364:17)","errno":-5,"code":"Z_BUF_ERROR`.

Comment: The URL being sent to the prerender server is correct. Prerender will send a 200 and render everything correctly once, then every subsequent request for that page results in a 304 on the prerender server and 500 from express.

Comment: Which version of express are you using? We've got a change that we'll push out soon to the prerender server that clears the in memory cache so that the 304s won't happen anymore.

Comment: I'm on Express 4.13.4.

Comment: The latest Prerender (v4.1.0) shouldn't have this issue anymore. We now clear the PhantomJS memory cache on each request. Can you try this with our latest version of Prerender?

Comment: I do intend to upgrade Prerender . . . just haven't had any time recently to work on my own projects. I will for sure let you know when I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to solve the problem, but I don't love it because I'm not sure what unintended consequences it might have.

In `/server.js` I defaulted the `PRERENDER_NUM_WORKERS` and `PRERENDER_NUM_ITERATIONS` to 1 and uncommented the `inMemoryHtmlCache()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var prerender = require('./lib');

var server = prerender({
    workers: process.env.PRERENDER_NUM_WORKERS || 1,
    iterations: process.env.PRERENDER_NUM_ITERATIONS || 1
});


server.use(prerender.sendPrerenderHeader());
// server.use(prerender.basicAuth());
// server.use(prerender.whitelist());
server.use(prerender.blacklist());
// server.use(prerender.logger());
server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());
server.use(prerender.httpHeaders());
server.use(prerender.inMemoryHtmlCache());
// server.use(prerender.s3HtmlCache());

server.start();
```

I'm open to a better answer, or at least assurance that this is an acceptable solution, and maybe an explanation as to why.